# MyBatis Configuration.xml with dataSource

Tags: xml, configuration, datasource, mybatis

I just keep getting this exception every time i try to connect to database.

#### Error building SqlSession.

#### The error may exist in SQL Mapper Configuration

#### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error creating document instance.  Cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The content of element type "dataSource" must match "(property)*".

Here is my Conifugration.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Config 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-config.dtd">
<configuration>
    <environments default="development">
        <environment id="development">
          <transactionManager type="JDBC"/>
          <dataSource type="POOLED">    
                <property name="driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
                <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3360/teste"/>
                <property name="username" value="root"/>
                <property name="password" value="root"/>
           </dataSource>
        </environment>
    </environments>
</configuration>
```

I've already searched google for this, looked up for datasource samples and it's just like the others and like the docs.

Does anyone know what it is?

Answer (score 2):

I looked at a working MyBatis configuration.xml file. I have the following three lines toward the end of my file, between `</environments>` and `</configuration>`.

```
<mappers>
  <mapper resource="YourHandbuiltOrMyBatisGeneratedMapper.xml"/>
</mappers>
```

The mappers are Java interfaces that help Java know how to CRUD (Create, Read, Update, and Delete). Corresponding to those letters are interfaces like int insert(); selectByPrimaryKey, int updateByExample; int deleteByExample.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The exception is saying that the stuff inside your `<dataSource/>` element must be zero or one `<property/>` tags. Might you have inadvertently included a hidden character in your XML source file, perhaps from copying and pasting? Other than that I do not see anything wrong with your XML.